# Can you update an edit log when a row is moved in a Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I currently have a spreadsheet that is appended each time a change is made to any other spreadsheet. It has been working well, except when it comes to recording the moving of a row. When a row gets moved, I would like to have a record added to the edit log that shows the old row number and the new row number. Is this possible?

Currently when a row is moved, this is the type of entry I get in edit log:

[image]

Comment: 1) `When a row gets moved` Would you please be more specific about what, exactly, you mean by "the row is moved" including the process followed. 2) `this is the type of entry I get in edit log:` The entry log is (presumably) being created by a script, please edit your question to include the script (as text-no snapshots please).Would you also include describe the type of trigger that you are using for this script.